# Transpose rows to columns using the first column as reference in unix shell

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I'm trying to transform this data:

```
EU842263.1.1492 AA.A_1 BB.B_2 CC.C_3
LN612956.1.1401 AA.A_1 BB.B_2 CC.C_3 DD.D_4 EE.E_5 FF.F_6
GU304497.1.1513 AA.A_1
AB905872.1.1334 AA.A_1 BB.B_2 CC.C_3 DD.D_4
```

Into this:

```
EU842263.1.1492 AA.A_1
EU842263.1.1492 BB.B_2
EU842263.1.1492 CC.C_3
LN612956.1.1401 AA.A_1
LN612956.1.1401 BB.B_2
LN612956.1.1401 CC.C_3
LN612956.1.1401 DD.D_4
LN612956.1.1401 EE.E_5
LN612956.1.1401 FF.F_6
GU304497.1.1513 AA.A_1
AB905872.1.1334 AA.A_1
AB905872.1.1334 BB.B_2
AB905872.1.1334 CC.C_3
AB905872.1.1334 DD.D_4
```

How can I achieve this?

Note that data (AA.A_1) are only representations of my real data (for example, 0.15.01610.011_528399).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in `Awk`, get a hash-map of values in first column as key and values in the rest of the row as hash values.

```
awk '
   {
       for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) 
           unique[$1]=(unique[$1]FS$i); next 
   } END { 
      for (i in unique) { 
           n=split(unique[i],temp); 
           for(j=1;j<=n;j++) 
               print i,temp[j] 
         } 
   }' file
```

should work on `awk` present on any POSIX compliant shell.

The steps:-

- The loop `for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)` runs for column number 2 till the last column in each line and a hash-map `unique` is created based on value of first column(`$1`) and other columns are designated from `$2` until `$NF`
- The part under `END` runs after all the lines are processed. We use the `split()` call to separate each value from the array and store them as individual elements in array `temp`.
- The we run a loop for all array elements in `temp` and print the index along with the element in the new array.